# How do I get text/html between consecutive <input>s?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since input tags aren't supposed to have closing tags, is there a simple way to extract the text/HTML in between a series of input tags? For example, for the below I want to retrieve `<b>Bob and Tim</b><br>Tim <i>after</i> Bob<br>`.

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" value="bob" size="4" />
    <b>Bob and Tim</b><br>
    <input type="text" value="tim" size="4" />
    Tim <i>after</i> Bob<br>
    <input type="button" value="get textbox values" id="mybutton" />
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLEZd/5/

I can get the textbox's values, but how do I accomplish the above?

Comment: I think you'll have to iterate through the children of `div#inputs` and keep the HTML of the ones you want. Alternatively you could clone the lot, strip out the input tags from the clone then just get `.innerHTML`

Comment: i added a new revision to your fiddle that works with cloning and using innerHTML [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLEZd/6/)

Comment: @TobiasKrogh I didn't see your answer at first. As I tested it works the best with odd HTML inserted between the <input>s. Please add it as an answer if you wish to earn more rep.

Comment: added it with a small explanation so that it actually is more than the fiddle... else it would not make sense as an own answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already more or less available in the fiddle and stated in the comment. but here also the code for the others directly with a small explanation:

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
  var tempContainer = $("#inputs").clone();
  tempContainer.find("input").remove();
  alert(tempContainer[0].innerHTML);
});​
```

this way the container is cloned and then the inputs get removed from the cloned container... in the end we have an innerHTML without the inputs

Answer (score 4):

With a minor markup change you can do it easily,

HTML:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" value="bob" id="bob" size="4" />
    <label for="bob"><b>Bob and Tim</b><br></label>
    <input type="text" value="tim" id="tim" size="4" />
    <label for="tim">Tim <i>after</i> Bob<br></label>
    <input type="button" value="get textbox values" id="mybutton" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
     alert($('label[for=' + this.id + ']').text());
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gLEZd/18/)

Incase if you don't like `label` tags, then simply wrap the contents inside a span like below,

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" value="bob" id="bob" size="4" />
    <span><b>Bob and Tim</b><br></span>
    <input type="text" value="tim" id="tim" size="4" />
    <span>Tim <i>after</i> Bob<br></span>
    <input type="button" value="get textbox values" id="mybutton" />
</div>
```

And in JS,

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
     alert($(this).next().text());
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gLEZd/11/)

Comment: Your first demo is a link to the original fiddle.  I'd fix it, but I don't know the link.

Comment: I'm using your no-label demo (JSFiddle #11). I don't see why it should happen, but when I add "Joe" after the </span> for Bob and Tim, Joe doesn't appear in the alerts. I did change text() for html(). I updated: http://jsfiddle.net/gLEZd/20/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
    var x = $('div#inputs :not(:input)');
    $.each(x, function() {
       console.log(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
    var x = $('div#inputs :not(:input)').filter(function() {
        return this.toString();
    });
    console.log(x); // x is the array of DOM Object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is desirable, but you can strip down to text like this:

```
alert ( $('#inputs').unwrap().text() );
```

This will also strip your `<b></b>` and other tags though.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if the information is linked to the input element, you should be using `<label for="">`.  Then you could easily access the value which is associated:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input id="input1" type="text" value="bob" size="4" />
    <label for="input1"><b>Bob and Tim</b><br></label>
    <input id="input2" type="text" value="tim" size="4" />
    <label for="input2 ">Tim <i>after</i> Bob<br></label>
    <input type="button" value="get textbox values" id="mybutton" />
</div>
```

Either:

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
    alert($(this).next('label').text());
  });
});
```

Or:

```
$("#mybutton").click( function() {
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
    alert($('label[for='+this.id+']').text());
  });
});
```